# undefined reference when the reference is in the header, and should exist

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

```
nachos
exception.o: In function `Exec(char*)':
/home/linux/ieng6/cs120f/cs120fbh/nachos/code/code/userprog/../userprog/exception.cc:223: undefined reference to `ProcessTable::Alloc(void*)'
progtest.o: In function `StartProcess(char*)':
/home/linux/ieng6/cs120f/cs120fbh/nachos/code/code/userprog/../userprog/progtest.cc:32: undefined reference to `ProcessTable::ProcessTable(int)'
/home/linux/ieng6/cs120f/cs120fbh/nachos/code/code/userprog/../userprog/progtest.cc:42: undefined reference to `ProcessTable::Alloc(void*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [nachos] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have the code in this gist

https://gist.github.com/hassanshaikley/0721dd9f791a94629bfc

this error is strange because I include the necessary components. : (

Comment: It's a linker error, not a compiler error... your `#include`'s are probably fine, but you need to link to the right libraries/object files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the following options in the compiler: 
-L to include your library search path 
-l to add the particular libraries that need to be included